# Conversion from ASCII values to Char

Tags: java, ascii

```
String source = "WEDGEZ"
char letter = source.charAt(i);
shift=5;
for (int i=0;i<source.length();i++){
if (source.charAt(i) >=65 && source.charAt(i) <=90 )
  letterMix =(char)(('D' + (letter - 'D' + shift) % 26));
}
```

Ok what I'm trying to do is take the string WEDGEZ, and shift each letter by 5, so W becomes B and E becomes J, etc. However I feel like there is some inconsistency with the numbers I'm using.

For the if statement, I'm using ASCII values, and for the 
`letterMix= statement`, I'm using the numbers from 1-26 (I think). Well actually, the question is about that too:

What does 
`(char)(('D' + (letter - 'D' + shift) % 26));` return anyway? It returns a char right, but converted from an int. I found that statement online somewhere I didn't compose it entirely myself so what exactly does that statement return.

The general problem with this code is that for W it returns '/' and for Z it returns _, which I'm guessing means it's using the ASCII values. I really dont know how to approach this.

Edit: New code

```
    for (int i=0;i<source.length();i++)
        {
        char letter = source.charAt(i);
        letterMix=source.charAt(i);
        if (source.charAt(i) >=65 && source.charAt(i) <=90 ){
            letterMix=(char)('A' + (  ( (letter - 'A') + input ) % 26));
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you looked up the actual ASCII values for your characters?

Comment: Yes I have, thats where I got 65 and 90 from.

Comment: This will work once you get past syntax errors and use 'A' instead of 'D'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I'm not sure if this homework, so i'll be stingy with the Code.

You're Writing a [Caesar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) with a shift of 5.

To address your `Z` -> `_` problem...I'm Assuming you want all the letters to be changed into encoded letters (and not weird Symbols). The problem is ASCII values of `A-Z` lie between 65 and 90.
When coding `Z` (for eg), you end up adding 5 to it, which gives u the value 95 (`_`).

What you need to do is Wrap around the available alphabets. First isolate, the relative position of the character in the alphabets (ie A = 0, B = 1 ...) You Need to subtract 65 (which is ASCII of `A`. Add your `Shift` and then apply `modulus 26`. This will cause your value to wrap around.

eg, it your encoding `Z`, (ASCII=90), so relative position is 25 (= 90 - 65).
now, 25 + 5 = 30, but you need the value to be within 26. so you take `modulus 26`
so `30 % 26` is `4` which is `E`.

So here it is

```
char letter = message(i);
int relativePosition = letter - 'A'; // 0-25
int encode = (relativePosition + shift) % 26
char encodedChar = encode + 'A' // convert it back to ASCII.
```

So in one line,

```
char encodedChar = 'A' + (  ( (letter - 'A') + shift ) % 26)
```

Note, This will work only for upper case, if your planning to use lower case, you'll need some extra processing.

You can use `Character.isUpperCase()` to check for upper case.

Comment: Thanks so much. That really helped! It fixed a lot of issues, but I'm still having an issue when I use negative shift values. For example, if I use -4 and I'm at the letter C, I want to get Y, but instead I get some punctuation. I ran the code manually on paper to see what I would get, and it should be working correctly. I dont know why it isnt. See edit for the code that I'm using.

Comment: @newtojava, That's coz in java, the `mod` operator gives out negative values as well...a simple  fix, would be to add `if(shift < 0) shift += 26;` before decrypting...and don't subtract it this time, use the same `+` sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for convert **ASCII values to Char**

```
class Ascii {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    char ch=sc.next().charAt(0);

    if(ch==' ') {

    int in=ch;

    System.out.println(in);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks